# Ember Cli on windows

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I m trying to get Ember cli on Windows 7.I have installed node and npm.
But when I type npm install -g ember-cli I get the following error.Is there anything that I am missing?[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix it but can you try running from a console other than cmd.exe? Try downloading git-bash https://msysgit.github.io/ Also - for what its worth. Running ember on windows is a horriblly slow experience for re-builds

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
npm package.json
```

to see errors in the `package.json` file. Otherwise try:

```
npm cache clean
```